# Make a generic class for hide and show password

Tags: swift

```
func hideShowPasswordButton() {

    var hideShowSize: CGSize = "12345".sizeWithAttributes([NSFontAttributeName:UIFont.systemFontOfSize(14.0)])
    var hideShow: UIButton = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.System)
    hideShow.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: hideShowSize.width, height: self.userPasswordText.frame.size.height)
    hideShow.setImage(hidePasswordImage, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    self.userPasswordText.rightView = hideShow
    self.userPasswordText.rightViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always
    hideShow.addTarget(self, action: "hideShowPasswordTextField:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
}

func hideShowPasswordTextField(sender: AnyObject) {

    var hideShow: UIButton = (self.userPasswordText.rightView as? UIButton)!
    if !self.userPasswordText.secureTextEntry {
        self.userPasswordText.secureTextEntry = true
        hideShow.setImage(hidePasswordImage, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    } else {
        self.userPasswordText.secureTextEntry = false
        hideShow.setImage(showPasswordImage, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    }
    self.userPasswordText.becomeFirstResponder()
}
```

I want to make a custom class with these functions so that I can use it in all view controllers.
Any help will be appreciated thank you

Answer (score 1):

You have 3 options:

**1) Subclass UITextField and use this subclassed textfield:**

```
 class PasswordField: UITextField {
    func hideShowPasswordButton() {

        var hideShowSize: CGSize = "12345".sizeWithAttributes([NSFontAttributeName:UIFont.systemFontOfSize(14.0)])
        var hideShow: UIButton = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.System)
        hideShow.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: hideShowSize.width, height: frame.size.height)
        hideShow.setImage(hidePasswordImage, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        rightView = hideShow
        rightViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always
        hideShow.addTarget(self, action: #selector(hideShowPasswordTextField(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    }

    func hideShowPasswordTextField(sender: AnyObject) {

        var hideShow: UIButton = (rightView as? UIButton)!
        if !secureTextEntry {
            secureTextEntry = true
            hideShow.setImage(hidePasswordImage, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        } else {
            secureTextEntry = false
            hideShow.setImage(showPasswordImage, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        }
        becomeFirstResponder()
    }
}
```

**2) Extend UITextField:**

```
extension UITextField {
    func hideShowPasswordButton() {

        var hideShowSize: CGSize = "12345".sizeWithAttributes([NSFontAttributeName:UIFont.systemFontOfSize(14.0)])
        var hideShow: UIButton = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.System)
        hideShow.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: hideShowSize.width, height: frame.size.height)
        hideShow.setImage(hidePasswordImage, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        rightView = hideShow
        rightViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always
        hideShow.addTarget(self, action: #selector(hideShowPasswordTextField(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    }

    func hideShowPasswordTextField(sender: AnyObject) {

        var hideShow: UIButton = (rightView as? UIButton)!
        if !secureTextEntry {
            secureTextEntry = true
            hideShow.setImage(hidePasswordImage, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        } else {
            secureTextEntry = false
            hideShow.setImage(showPasswordImage, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        }
        becomeFirstResponder()
    }
}
```

**3) Create protocol for e.g. ViewController and set its default implementation:**

```
protocol PasswordHidable: class {
    var userPasswordText: UITextField { get }

    func hideShowPasswordButton()
    func hideShowPasswordTextField(sender: AnyObject)
}

extension PasswordHidable {
    func hideShowPasswordButton() {

        var hideShowSize: CGSize = "12345".sizeWithAttributes([NSFontAttributeName:UIFont.systemFontOfSize(14.0)])
        var hideShow: UIButton = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.System)
        hideShow.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: hideShowSize.width, height: self.userPasswordText.frame.size.height)
        hideShow.setImage(hidePasswordImage, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        self.userPasswordText.rightView = hideShow
        self.userPasswordText.rightViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always
        hideShow.addTarget(self, action: #selector(hideShowPasswordTextField(_:), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    }

    func hideShowPasswordTextField(sender: AnyObject) {

        var hideShow: UIButton = (self.userPasswordText.rightView as? UIButton)!
        if !self.userPasswordText.secureTextEntry {
            self.userPasswordText.secureTextEntry = true
            hideShow.setImage(hidePasswordImage, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        } else {
            self.userPasswordText.secureTextEntry = false
            hideShow.setImage(showPasswordImage, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        }
        self.userPasswordText.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried the first solution. But the hide and show image does not show up. In my main view controller I have outlets created from the storyboard for the TextField. In the storyboard I have changed the class to Password field , but does not seem to work